# Web scraping para coleta de artigos científicos na ScienceDirect

Tags: r, pdf

Estou tentando usar R para selecionar artigos da página do ScienceDirect usando keywords. Consegui extrair pdfs de uma página semana passada, utilizando as informações do source da página. O código usando foi o seguinte:

```
base.url = "http"
doc.html <- htmlParse(base.url)
doc.links <- xpathSApply(doc.html, "//a/@href")
pdf.url <- doc.links[grep("http:/", doc.links)]
dat<-as.data.frame(pdf.url)
colnames(dat)<-"url"
dat$pdf<-unlist(lapply(dat$url, FUN = function(x) strsplit(x, "/")[[1]][3]))
lapply(dat$pdf, function(x)
download.file(paste("http//pdf/", x, sep=""), 
paste(download.folder, x, sep=""), mode = "wb", cacheOK=TRUE))
```

Alguém tem alguma sugestão de como posso fazer o mesmo para a Science Direct?

Comment: Acho que extrair os PDFs assim viola os termos de uso daquele site, não? Os conteúdos não são pagos?

Comment: Sim, mas tenho vpn (permissão para coletar remotamente os artigos) da USP (sou aluna).

Answer (score 6):

Tenho uma sugestão usando os pacotes RSelenium e XML. O RSelenium controla um navegador de internet (no caso aqui, o firefox) e permite que você navegue automaticamente, por linha de comando. Isso é muito vantajoso para páginas com muitos códigos complexos e JavaScript. Não é a solução mais fácil no entanto. Acredito que alguém possa postar aqui um exemplo usando o pacote `rvest`...

Vamos lá então:

Instalando...

```
    #install.packages("devtools")
    #install.packages("RCurl",dep=T)
    #install.packages("XML",dep=T)
    #install.packages("RJSONIO",dep=T)

    #library(devtools)
    #install_github("ropensci/RSelenium")
```

Agora carregamos o pacote RSelenium

```
    library(RSelenium)
```

E instalamos um servidor Java/Selenium para controlar o Firefox. É um programa que fica aberto junto com o R e serve como uma interface de "tradução" entre o R e o navegador.

```
    checkForServer() #baixando um servidor do Selenium (so precisa fazer uma vez)
    startServer() # mantenha essa janela aberta
```

Tenha o Mozilla firefox instalado!! Vamos abri-lo:

```
    firefox_con <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", 
                                port = 4444, 
                                browserName = "firefox"
    )
```

Abrindo o firefox (a navegacao vai se dar nele)

```
    firefox_con$open() # mantenha essa janela aberta

    # Definindo a pagina de interesse
    url <- "http://www.sciencedirect.com"
```

Navegamos até a pagina de interesse no firefox

```
    firefox_con$navigate("http://www.sciencedirect.com")
```

E inserimos o termo de busca ("Biology") na caixa de texto. Depois pressionamos ENTER para realizar a busca:

```
    busca <- firefox_con$findElement(using = "css selector", "#qs_all")
    busca$sendKeysToElement(list("Biology", key="enter"))
```

Agora o resto é com o XML:

```
    # Extraindo o codigo fonte da pagina
    pagina <- xmlRoot(
                    htmlParse(
                            unlist(firefox_con$getPageSource())
                    )) 

    # Extraindo os links para os PDF (alguns deles podem requerer acesso pago...)
    pdf_links <- xpathSApply(pagina, '//span[@class="pdfIconSmall"]/..', xmlGetAttr, "href")
    links_incompletos <- grep("^/", pdf_links)
    pdf_links[links_incompletos] <- paste0(url,pdf_links[links_incompletos])

    # Seus links
    pdf_links

    # links que funcionam (gratuitos)
    pdf_gratis <- pdf_links[grep("article",pdf_links)]

    # DOI (o DOI será o nome do arquivo salvo)
    DOI <- substr(pdf_gratis,50,66)

   # Fazendo o download
   ### setwd... defina um diretorio...

    for(i in 1:length(pdf_gratis)){
            download.file(pdf_gratis[i], 
                          paste0(DOI[i],".pdf"),
                          mode = "wb")
    }
```

Espero que tenha ajudado.

Comment: Muito grata pela sua respota!
Os passos deram super certo. Só não consegui ainda gravar os arquivos em pdf no meu work diretory.

Comment: @Karla, com o loop for acima, eu consigo baixar/salvar os PDFs normalmente... estranho. Essa parte do código não funcionou pra vc? Deu algum erro? Nesse último caso, que mensagem retorna?

Comment: RogérioJB, ele salva um arquivo em pdf que deveria conter todos os pdfs baixados, no entanto, o arquivo está em branco.

Comment: Então, na verdade, não existe nenhuma mensagem de erro no R, apenas o arquivo salvo em branco.